# Django: Filtering model entries that doesn't have a related OneToOne entry in another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have two models

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
```

another one

```
class Sell_info(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    bike = models.OneToOneField(Bike, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sell_info")
```

I am filtering those Bikes that don't have a related Sell_info entry available.

```
bikes = Bike.objects.filter('sell_info__isnull=True')
```

but it get this problem

```
ValueError at /new-bikes/
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Pass keyword arguments not a string to filter: `Bike.objects.filter(sell_info__isnull=True)`

Comment: Can't you just use `Sell_info.objects.filter(bikes=null)`

Comment: @lain Shelvington ohh, worked. sometimes small mistakes can wreck you.

Comment: @Astros I need Bikes, not Sell_info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass keyword argument to filter, not string

```
bikes = Bike.objects.filter(sell_info__isnull=True)
```